# Offline MVC5 and EF6 stock management application sync when online from multiple user

Tags: wpf, asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework-6, microsoft-sync-framework, jaydata

The Requirements
A secure billing Application that works offline on multiple desktop purpose, sync data when connected to the online server
After login to the server, user can track on remaining stock and generate sales report.
Not looking for HTML5 catch solution as it is not secure
Now my question.. is it possible using Entity framework 6 and MVC and Microsoft sync? How should I start?

Comment: What does "offline" mean when talking about a *web application*? ASP.NET MVC is a *web framework* that runs on a server, not desktops. If you mean, how can you have the *browsers* work offline and sync with the server - HTML5 offline storage is the only option, and it *is* secure unless you have a very *specific* requirement. Anything else would require addins which are *not* secure

Comment: While there's no mention of WPF in your question (apart from in the currently mistagged tags), this sounds like it might be easier to develop as a desktop app rather than a web app.

Comment: Thanks @PanagiotisKanavos I found the same solution but as I mentioned I can't use HTML5 offline storage. I think I've to create two solution for it, may be WPF and MVC app, one for offline and other for online. Also have to provide sync between two here comes Microsoft sync framework. But not sure if is it possible.

Comment: Thanks @goobering I'm considering WPF as the solution, but can you tell how can I proceed..d appreciate some steps..

Comment: Why do you think that your own local storage will be more secure than offline storage? Sync frameworks *sync* data between storages, they don't store or secure the data.

Comment: If you were going to produce this in WPF then you could implement back end storage using Entity Framework, then data access using Web API 2, then client interaction and offline storage using WPF and some kind of local storage system. What local storage system depends heavily on your requirements - large amounts of data/data with security requirements you'll need some kind of DB, small amounts of data/no security requirements you might be able to get away with XML. An MVC project can be hooked up to your Entity Framework project for online activity.

Comment: Thanks a lot @goobering. I'm gonna follow the above steps. I think I will find a solution with that..and will update if it'll work